# Convert date integer to text?

Tags: php, date

Is there anyway to convert the value of idate("z") to a date format that reads the Day, Month, and Year? My code looks like this:

```
$date_int = idate("z");
$date_text = strtotime($date_int);
$date = date("l, F j, Y", $date_text);
```

For some reason, it's still echoing Thursday, January 1, 1970.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`idate("z")` is incorrect as that will return the day of the year.  It seems like you want `idate("U")`, but in that case just use `date()` without the second parameter, it will assume `time()`.  Example:

```
$date = date("l, F j, Y");
```

That should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

`idate("z")` will only return the day of the year. Today being `74`. `strtotime` will not understand `74` as a parsing format. Therefore `date()` fails all together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the date of the CURRENT YEAR:

```
$dayOfYear = 80;
print date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($dayOfYear - idate("z") . " day")); // Wednesday, March 21, 2012

$dayOfYear = 1;
print date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($dayOfYear - idate("z") . " day")) // Monday, January 2, 2012
```